# How to resolve list of objects not rendering

Tags: reactjs

Hello I am new to ReactJS so I am just practising  on working with states and also so a good practice for a starting point I thought why not the classic TODO App.

So I do not know why the object is not being rendered or being added because when I even console logged the object It did not even show that it's empty or anything the was literally no output so I do not know where I could have went wrong with this methods

**Code Below App.js:** This is the file that has all the methods and state control of the TODO APP

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import style from './stylesheet/app.css'
import ListItems from './ListItems'

class App extends Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            items:[],
            currentItem:{
                notes: '',
                key: ''
            }
        }
        this.handleInput = this.handleInput.bind(this);
        this.addItem = this.addItem.bind(this);
    }

    // Handling user Input to save on before I add to the Items
   //  this.state.currentItems is a temporary store place for TODO'S       

    handleInput(e){
        this.setState({
            currentItem: {
                notes: e.target.value,
                key: Date.now()
            }
        })

    }

    // After handling input input once the add button is clicked I want to add 
    // the the object in the temporary storage into the permanent store place that is the 
    // this.state.items --> permanent store place  

    addItem(e){
        e.preventDefault()
    
        const newTodo = this.state.currentItem;
   
        if (newTodo.text !== " "){
            const newTodos = [...this.state.items, newTodo];
            this.setState({
                items:newTodos,
                currentItem:{
                    notes:'',
                    key:''
                }
            })
        }
    
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div className="container" style={style}>

                <div className='todo-form'>

                    <form id="form">
                        <input type="text" 
                        placeholder="Enter in your todo's" 
                        value={this.state.currentItem.notes}
                        onChange={this.handleInput}></input>

                        <button type="submit" onSubmit={this.addItem}>Add Todo</button>
                    </form>

                    <ListItems items={this.state.items}/>
            
                </div>

            
            

            </div>
        )
    }

}

export default App
```

**Code Below ListItems.js:** This file contains code where I tried to map through the ojects to display the TODO'S

```
import React from 'react';


const ListItems = (props) =>{

    const items = props.items;
    const listItems = items.map(item =>{
        return <div className="todo-list" key={item.key}> <p>{item.key}</p> </div>

    })

    return(
        <div>
            {listItems}
        </div>
    )
}

export default ListItems
```

Can you please help me figure out where I could be going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works perfectly fine. Just add `addItem` function to form element, so it preventsDefault correctly and doesnt reload whole page:

```
 <form id="form" onSubmit={this.addItem}>
```

See here: https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-gareth-vlkmx